# Send signal to serial port (RS232) through web using .NET framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, serial-port

I have taken a project where I control a small car through the web.

The car is programmed using PIC assembly and awaits commands through the serial port. It has a controlling program written in VB6. This is ready.

I want to have this car connected to a PC hereby server which will send the serial port commands from a web interface. The VB6 program I want to be upgraded to a .NET application.

1. Can I send signal to RS232 via ASPX pages that reside on IIS?
2. If not, how could I achieve such functionality? A WPF or WF program maybe?
3. If it is a WPF or WF program how I will transfer commands through a web application? How can I minimize the delay?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to communicate with the serial port of the client machine from a web application, ASP.NET is not the right option. You can consider WPF application (XBAPP). When it runs under full trust mode, it can access the serial port on the client machine.

In case you go for WPF application, you can think of some service or COMET (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) like page that can get commands from the server continually. Or you may opt for some step by step synchronous request-response system for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is missing here. As far as I know, a car does not come with a PC. So let me understand your question.

- Have a small circuit or a device with a PIC controller. Which is
- probably programmed with a C or assembly language. This in vehicle
- device has the capability to control your car through digital
- input/outputs you want to communicate your command to this device

Hope this is what you want. If this is the case, then you cannot use RS232. You need to have a GSM/GPRS modem or some other WIFI mode of communicating your device with your server/computer which has a static ip.

Once you have such a server and a device with this capability, you can communicate either through an asp .net polling requset as Mr. Kangkan suggested or even use sockets to communicate beween your car's device and the server.

Mostly these kinds of things are used in GPS tracking and related systems. RS232 can mostly be used as a configuration program IMHO.

Comment: No the car has a VB6 interface and gets signal through RS232. I am not going for wireless communication for this semester's project.Next semester i will modify it to have BT aor Wifi connectivity.